# Detarame / 出鱈目 literal translation?

Tags: translation, etymology

I recently encountered the Japanese phrase 出鱈目/デタラメ/detarame to mean... well, what we in English generally refer to as bull****. Which, the implications in the word from what it means is pretty straightforward.

I'm interested in what the literal translation would amount to. As far as I can tell from looking up the individual characters, it has something to do with (bulging?) cod eyes (codswallop?), but I'm not sure why they'd be equated to-- let's call it bullcrap.

This is about etymology more than use! I'm interested in what it means in Japanese, rather than what it's equivalent to.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14115/30454

Comment: Thanks! The full phrase really helps. Do you know why the word for cod/鱈 came to be associated with "saying anything", or is it just a homonym?

Comment: It is *ateji*: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15179/43676

Comment: Oh, I see! Well, it's a bit disappointing there isn't a more involving origin to it, but that's true of all languages! They can't all be interesting full-backstory yojijukugo. Thank you both very much for the background! Your answers were very much not cod eyes ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Under what circumstances is でたらめ used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/under-what-circumstances-is-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89%e3%82%81-used)